# Any way to check if an onSnapshot is still active?

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

A few times I've noticed, for whatever reason, the connection between the browser tab and Firestore has been severed, and it does not always re-connect successfully.

Is there any way to reliably check if your onSnapshot is still actively listening?

Either by event triggering or polling every so often.

Using in a nextjs/ react environment.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement `catch()` on the `onSnapshot` method and create a specific function inside it that could notify you if the listener fails. Also, you can use Cloud Monitoring which can collect metrics, events, and metadata from Google Cloud products. Cloud Monitoring includes the Cloud Firestore metrics.

For more information, you may want to checkout this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/monitor-usage#cloud-monitoring).